# DBUNIT and Spring.. cant load dataset file

Tags: spring, junit, dbunit, spring-test

Im trying to test my dao layer. So I have created an embedded DB. In my junit tests i am struggling to get the data to load:

So my create script is:

CREATE SCHEMA test_schema AUTHORIZATION DBA;

CREATE TABLE test_schema.tableOne (....)

After the database is created.. i try and load in data using

```
@Test
public void testFind() throws Exception {

    IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File(
            "./src/test/resources/sampleData.xml"
            ));
            IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new   DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource);
            DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(dbConn, dataSet);  


}
```

my dataset file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <dataset>
<tableOne state_id="0" previous_state_id="0" player_uid="222222" /> 
  </dataset>
```

After tryibng to execute the above i get user lacks privilege or object not found TABLEONE...

(btw my database is created using spring 3 embedded hsql)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it sorted..

IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource, "TEST_SCHEMA");
        dbConn.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);

Apparently when i create the connection i have to specify the schema name as above but also in CAPS!

the dataset can then be set as follows

```
<test_schema.tableone..... etc
```